# Prove that the logarithmic mean is less than the power mean.

Tags: analysis, inequality

Prove that the logarithmic mean is less than the power mean.

$$L(a,b)=\frac{a-b}{\ln(a)-\ln(b)} < M_p(a,b) = \left(\frac{a^p+b^p}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$ such that $$p\geq \frac{1}{3}$$ That is the $\frac{1}{p}$ root of the power mean.

Comment: I'm currently working on the problem. I' wanted to attempt induction but this will not work I assume. My professor wanted to pull out an a from both equations, and add them together when p=1/3. But I was not sure how this would help.

Comment: Any hint would be helpful. I am stuck and I can not get past this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the inequality of Power Means, it is sufficient to prove this for $p = \frac13$.  Also WLOG we can assume $a > b > 0 \implies x = \frac{a}b > 1$.  So the inequality we are left to show is, for $x > 1$:
$$\frac{x-1}{\log x} < \left(\frac{x^{1/3}+1}2 \right)^3$$

Simplifying using $x = t^3$, this is equivalent to showing for $t > 1$

$$\log t > \frac{8(t^3-1)}{3(t+1)^3}$$

At $t=1, LHS = 0 = RHS$, so it is sufficient to show that LHS increases faster than RHS, or 
$$\frac1t > \frac{8(1+t^2)}{(1+t)^4} \iff 8t(1+t^2) < (1+t)^4 \iff (t-1)^4 > 0$$

Comment: Why is it enough to prove this for the p=1/3 case only? And how did you get to that first equation from the original? I'm going to attempt to figure this out in the mean time.

Comment: @Macavity +1 Nice :)

Comment: @Macavity I see that you pulled out a "b" from both sides and substituted x=a/b. I see that. But, I do not see who you simplified using x=t^3 to attain the second equation. Nor do I see why. I don't simply want to know how the proof is done but I also want to understand why; this is critical for me. Edit: I see how you manipulated to attain the second equation. I will continue to work with this.

Comment: If you prove for $p=\frac13$, then the Power Means Inequality (check for e.g. https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Power_Mean_Inequality) assures the inequality will hold for $p > \frac13$.  The rest is algebra and manipulation as you noticed.

Comment: @Macavity I am truly thankful for your help. It means a lot to me. I am on spring break and I can not get to my professor. Once again, thank you and r9m.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $e:\mathbb{R}\cup\{0\} \to\mathbb{R}$;

$e(s)=\dfrac{x^s-y^s}{s}$, when $s\neq 0$, and $e(s)=\ln(x)-\ln(y)$, when $s=0$ (where, $x,y>0$).

Note that $e$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}\cup\{0\}$.

Further, $e(s)=\int_y^x v^{s-1}\,dv$,

Since, for arbitrary $a,b,s,t\in \mathbb{R}$,

$a^2e(s)+2abe(\frac{s+t}{2})+b^2e(t)=\int_y^x a^2v^{s-1}+2abv^{\frac{s+t}{2}-1} +b^2v^{t-1}\,dv=\int_y^x(av^{\frac{s-1}{2}}+bv^{\frac{t-1}{2}})^2\,dv\ge0$,

it follows from the negative condition of discriminant that, $e(s)e(t)\ge (e(\frac{s+t}{2}))^2$,

i.e., $\log(e(s))$ is a convex function on $\mathbb{R}\cup\{0\}$, that is for arbitrary non negative values $r,s,t$ we have

$(t-s)\ln e(r)+(r-t)\ln e(s)+(s-r)\ln e(t)\ge0$ .

Taking anti-log, $\large(\frac{e(s)}{e(r)})^{\frac{1}{s-r}}\le (\frac{e(t)}{e(r)})^{\frac{1}{t-r}}$, for $t>s$

Therefore, $E(r,s):=(\frac{e(s)}{e(r)})^{\frac{1}{s-r}}=(\frac{e(r)}{e(s)})^{\frac{1}{r-s}}=E(s,r)$ is increasing in $r$ and $s$,

I.e. $E(2s,s)=\large\left(\frac{x^s+y^s}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{s}}$ and $E(s,0) = \frac{x^s-y^s}{s(\ln x - \ln y)}$

$E(2s,s)\ge E(s,s) \ge E(s,0)\ge E(1,0)$, if $s>1$.

It remains to verify that $E(2/3,1/3)\ge E(1,0)$

Follow Macavity's proof :)

**EDIT:** (proof by F. Burke) From a geometric point of view the final inequality can also be derived from the Simpson's $3/8$ rule:

$\displaystyle \int_c^d f(x)\,dx = \left(\dfrac{f(c)+3f(\frac{2c+d}{3})+3f(\frac{c+2d}{3})+f(d)}{8}\right)(d-c) - \dfrac{(d-c)^5}{6480}f^{(4)}(\theta)$, where $\theta \in (c,d)$.

For the function $f(x) = e^x$, with limits $c =\ln a$ and $d = \ln b$, the rule suggests,

$$\displaystyle \int_{\ln a}^{\ln b} e^x\,dx \le \left(\dfrac{e^{\ln a}+3e^{\frac{2\ln a + \ln b}{3}}+3e^{\frac{\ln a + 2\ln b}{3}}+e^{\ln b}}{8}\right)(\ln b- \ln a)$$

i.e., $\displaystyle (b-a) \le \left(\dfrac{a^{1/3}+b^{1/3}}{2}\right)^3(\ln b - \ln a)$.

Comment: Yeah I'm only a junior math wise. I'm sure if I gave it some effort I could understand your proof, but my professor wanted us to go the way Mac did, so I will do so. Thank you very much for your help though, I always appreciate the help.

Comment: @user133156 It's Ok. I was trying to answer your first question .. "
Why is it enough to prove this for the p=1/3 case only?" .. These are Generalized Stolasky Means ... I just gave an approach to proving the inequalities involving these means :)

Comment: Yeah I see that now, but I don't think our professor ever went over that haha. Thank you though :) I'm currently writing up the LaTex for the proof, if you'd like to look at it when I'm done.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my proof. I feel like I made a huge leap at the end. I was not sure how to embed my LaTex code, it would not work. So I took screenshots. The last two lines, I have a gut feeling that I am missing a key step that links the two.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: small typo in the last line .. the power should be $\frac {1}{p}$ not 3

Comment: @r9m Yes. I have changed that. Could you explain to me exactly how I can go from the last few lines to the conclusion of the proof? I feel like there must be something missing. I don't have a particular reason, but it's just a feeling.

Comment: now its showing $p$, make it $\frac {1}{p}$, add the line $\large(\frac{a^p+b^p}{2})^{\frac{1}{p}} \ge \large(\frac{a^\frac{1}{3}+b^\frac{1}{3}}{2})^3$, for $p\ge \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: @r9m Crap I see that. I'll fix it. You mean add that line prior to the generalized form correct?

Comment: Fixed the problem.

Comment: @Frumpy Can you tell exactly what wasn't working with the LaTeX code?  If you paste it into your answer I'd be happy to fix it for you.  An answer formatted in LaTeX / MathJax would be much more helpful to this site and to users viewing your answer.

Comment: @Goos Well I'm new to this website and I'm not sure how to use MathJax. I put the double $$ signs when needed before and after but it only came up as code.

Comment: @Frumpy Can you paste the LaTeX code at http://paste.ubuntu.com/ ?  Then I will put it into this answer for you and maybe that will help you know how MathJax works.